# Bench mark old rails application 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an application that could benchmark or check what pages makes my application slow and causing high cpu usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet). It's a rails plugin/gem to kill N+1 queries and unused eager loading.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and give you a feedback. ^^